# Pug - Is there a way to get the output markup from a pug mixin as a escaped markup?

Tags: html, tags, escaping, pug

The idea is to have the possibility to use the same mixin used to build some componet for a project also to get the html output to use inside `<code>` tags to build a small documetation.

So here I have my configurable component as a mixin

```
mixin myComponentMixin(params)
```

and I would like to use in this way (wrong code, just to get the idea )

```
pre
  code
    :escape
      +myComponentMixin(params)
```

Is the a way to get the same result?

**EDIT**

I found a workaround

```
pre
  code
    script( type='text/plain' style='display: block;' )
      +myComponentMixin(params)
```

In this way is possibile use the mixin output as escaped text as `<code>` wants

Comment: You might be able to write a custom filter for this, as your example code suggests. Another (messier) way to do this if you're using something like Gulp would be to create a gulp task that compiles each of your mixins into a HTML fragment file before your main compilation task. Then you could `include` those precompiled HTML fragments into your documentation Pug files.

Comment: Maybe I have to try to put the mixin's output inside a var, if it's possibile and after that pass it to a custom filters to encode it

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it that way.

Comment: @Sean I found a workaround using `script( type='text/plain' style='display: block;' )` instead of :escape

Comment: Interesting; wouldn't have thought of that

Comment: Thanks for updating with the solution you found. The proper way to do that is to add it as an answer to your question and accept that answer. Questions shouldn't include the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Webpack, try the [@webdiscus/pug-loader](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader).

See the [examples for highlighted markdown in Pug](https://webdiscus.github.io/pug-loader/pug-filters/markdown.html).

Here is the [github-readme-preview](https://github.com/webdiscus/github-readme-preview) project used the pug filters to preview in the browser a markdown file with GitHub styling.

Comment: Maybe I did not say it clear enough. I'm more interested in reusing the Mixins I've created to build documentation so that I don't have to rewrite and maintain their html markup. 

The problem is that I can't get their own encoded version of the markup from these mixins to use within the code tag.

It is not possible to use the :encode filter above these mixins and I was wondering if there was an alternative way.

Comment: @spazione That's good context that I think is worth editing the question to add.